# AngularJS load json from file in services.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, service

I want to load json from a file, driverStandings.json (you see it left in the structure from the image). I use a service API to load this data in. I use following code(right in the image).

[image: Left the project sturcture, right the service class]

When I compile, I don't get my drivers list, I get following error list

```
TypeError: url.replace is not a function
    at angular.js:8557
    at sendReq (angular.js:8426)
    at $get.serverRequest (angular.js:8146)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
    at angular.js:11768
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
    at done (angular.js:8450)
```

What is a TypeError and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post live code not images. Makes it very hard to copy to help create answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `jsonp` as method for a static json resource and you are nesting another `$http` call as the url to the outer ones

Just use the inner $http and get rid of the outer ones

```
FAPI.getDrivers = function(id){
    return $http.get( ... path to json file ...)
}
```

Comment: You mean: F1API.getDrivers = function() {
        return  $http.get('/app/data/driverStandings.json');
    } ??

Comment: Yes...exactly what I mean

Comment: Perfect, you derserve a big heart (L)

Answer (score 1):

```
angular
    .module('FomulaOne.services', {})
    .factory('F1APIService', function ($http)
        {
            function http_get (url, doneFunc, failFunc)
            {
                var promise = $http.get(url);

                promise.success(doneFunc);

                if ( failFunc ) // optional error catch
                    promise.error( failFunc );

                return promise;
            }

            return {
                getDrivers: function (doneFunc, failFunc)
                {
                    return http_get( '/app/data/driversStandings.json', doneFunc, failFunc );
                },
                getDriverDetails: function (id, doneFunc, failFunc)
                {
                    return http_get( '/app/data/' + id + '/driversStandings.json', doneFunc, failFunc );
                },
                getDriverRaces: function (id, doneFunc, failFunc)
                {
                    return http_get( '/app/data/' + id + '/results.json', doneFunc, failFunc );
                }
            };
        });
```

To use

```
F1APIService.getDriverDetails(
    123,
    function (response)
    {
        // Do stuff on success
    },
    function (response)
    {
        // Do stuff on error
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), url requires an string with a proper url, just remove the $http.get from there and it should work, but first take a look at the doc.